# Can the adp2 device be flashed with 2.0?

Tags: android, operating-system, adp

Can the adp2 that I just bought through the Android Market be flashed with Android 2.0?  I can't find anything anywhere.  The HTC developer support only has system images for the adp1 and adp2 phones up to 1.6.

If it can't I will be sending the phone back for a full refund.

Comment: be flashed? do you mean does it support flash?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTC developer page](http://developer.htc.com/google-io-device.html#s3), only 1.5 and 1.6 are available for the ADP2. If you want 2.1 you're likely going to want to get a Nexus One.